# Potability measure of water on Volcanic Mountains

Tags: drinking-water

Is it safe to drink water found from natural resources on the Volcanic Mountains?
Considering Chemistry part of it, What could go wrong if I have no way to boil it, at the most I can filter it with multiple layers of garment.

Comment: If there's chemical contamination (probably sulfur), no amount of boiling will help. Distillation might, depending on what it's contaminated with.

Comment: Related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/climbing-volcanic-mountains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Volcanic water is not a problem. Volvic is a popular spring water in France it filters through an extinct volcano. Of course any water could have nasty chemicals in it. Filtering through a garment will not remove chemicals nor will boiling the water. You should ask locals about the water quality or look for springs that have man made constructions such as a basin and a pipe.